# Turnkey Linux and GIT

Tags: ubuntu, git, turnkey-linux

I installed Turnkey Linux http://www.turnkeylinux.org/revision-control to have a Git server. The installation went fine and I created a user to use with git. It comes with a preinstalled repo called "helloworld.git".

In order to test GIT, I did `git clone git://192.168.56.101/git/helloworld.git` and it cloned the repo just fine. I then went into the repo and made a change and did commited. Then I added the remote by doing `git remote add hassm@192.168.56.101:helloworld.git`

I then did a push and it asked for my password as expecting but then said `helloworld.git does not appear to be a git repository`

Am I not putting the right location for the remote repo? Also how do I go about creating my own repo on the server. I am fairly new at managing a GIT server. Thanks.

Comment: What does `git remote -v` say? Did you give your remote a name (`git remote add name URL`)?

Comment: Yes I did. It connects to the server, asks for my password, it just says the repo does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1) When you clone a repo, the original repo is automatically setup as the origin/master of your new copy. You do not have to add it in as a remote. 'git push' with no arguments should go back to that repo.

2) You have a typo in your remote repo. You are pulling from git://192.168.56.101/git/helloworld.git but trying push back to git://192.168.56.101/helloworld.git  Note the dropped "/git/" directory in the path. That's why git was complaining - it wasn't finding a valid git repository (because it couldn't find *any* repository).  But, as I said, you don't need this step anyway.